# How do I specify a typealias of a scene conforming to a specific protocol?

Tags: swift, swift3

I want to define a type which refers to only objects which are:

1. Members of a subclass of a given class
2. Conform to a specific protocol

How can I specify such a type?  For instance, I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
//Define a class
class MyClass {}

//Define a protocol
protocol MyProtocol {}

//Define an extension specific to this class and protocol
extension MyProtocol where Self : MyClass {}

//This works for multiple protocols, but not a class and a protocol
typealias MyAlias = MyClass & MyProtocol
```

Comment: Don't you just want `MyClass` to implement `MyProtocol`? Then you would get `typealias MyAlias = MyClass` which would be kind of redundant

Comment: No, because I don't need a dependency between `MyClass` and `MyProtoco`l.  It's possible to have `MyClass` subclasses which don't implement `MyProtocol`.